# How to test Material UI Select Component with jest and playwright?

Tags: material-ui, playwright

I want to select an option via playwright, but I cannot select an option. What is wrong?

MUI

```
          <Select
            data-testid="color"
          >
            <MenuItem value="red">
              red
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="green">
              green
            </MenuItem>

          </Select>
```

test

```
await page.selectOption("data-testid=color", "red)
```

Comment: how about await `page.selectOption("[data-testid=color]", "red")`

Comment: @hardkoded I tried, but it also does not work

Answer (score 0):

There might be some whitespaces if what you copies is accurate. I'd try to select by value:

```js
await page.selectOption('[data-testid=color]', { value: 'red' });
```